# Validation doesn't ignore field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the plugin `JQuery-Validate`. I actually created a form which have the following inputs:

```
<div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
    <label for="operator-password" class="bmd-label-floating"> <?= lang('password') ?> *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="operator-password" name="password" >
</div>

<div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
    <label for="operator-confirm-password" class="bmd-label-floating"> <?= lang('confirm_pwd') ?> *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="operator-confirm-password" name="confirm_password">
</div>
```

essentially, I apply the class `.ignore` dynamically if a certain condition happend, eg:

```
$('#operator-password, #operator-confirm-password').addClass('ignore');
```

when I submit the form, I will get below the two inputs:

> Field is required!

that's weird 'cause I configured the `validate` to skip the input with `.ignore` class:

```
$('#operator-form').validate({
    rules: {
        ignore: ".ignore",
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        confirm_password: {
            equalTo: '#password'
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention `ignore` outside of `rules` like following

```
$('#operator-form').validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        confirm_password: {
            equalTo: '#password'
        }
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rL60wes2/